# How to add fields into many2one by module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am building a module with a many2one field (to be inserted into CRM module) but when I click on add a new value, the fields I created are not showing:

[What it happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9R1Q.png)

I wrote this in my files:

**module.py**

```
class tipo_facturacion(models.Model):
  _name = "tipo_facturacion"
  name = fields.Char(string="Tipo Facturación", size=50, required=True)
  otro = fields.Char("Esto", required=True)

class cant_neg_crm(models.Model):  
        _inherit = "crm.lead"
        _columns = {
        'modo_facturacion': fields.many2one('tipo_facturacion' ,'Tipo Facturacion'),   
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the hussle. It worked now, but it is showing this instead of the Char value:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: if the filed'd model (model of many2one field) contains name field then it shows name field over there other wise it will take the **model name, id**. If name field is not there then you can set `_rec_name='other_field_name'` by setting this property in model you will see the value of that field in many2one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define that field in view as well, by view inheritance you can do it.

```
class tipo_facturacion(models.Model):
    _name = "tipo_facturacion"

    name = fields.Char(string="Tipo Facturación", size=50, required=True)
    otro = fields.Char("Esto", required=True)

class cant_neg_crm(models.Model):  
    _inherit = "crm.lead"
    _columns = {
        'modo_facturacion': fields.many2one('tipo_facturacion' ,'Tipo Facturacion'),   
    }
```

Now add this field (Many2one) to the existing view using inheritance.

(Base view ID => crm.crm_case_form_view_leads) it might differ in your case.

```
<record id="new_view_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.form</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
    <field name="priority" eval="40"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- field name which you specify here after then new field will be added. -->
        <field name="existing_field_name" position="after">
            <field name="modo_facturacion" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

> Similarly you can add field in list view as well. Condition is only
>   that you must add this py file in __init__.py and xml file in
>   __openerp__.py file and restart server and upgrade/install module.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that and see how it works!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working. When opening the many2one field, it shows other fields... Such as EAN13 and many other that have nothing to do with the other fields created.

Thank you for your help!